# Remote Desktop connection is ignoring saved credentials

Tags: remote-desktop, credentials

I have an RDP (Remote Desktop connectin) file.
When I view/edit the file I can see that the username and password are stored in it,
but when I connect to the remote server using the file the server shows me a login prompt with empty username and password.

Does anyone know what may be the problem?
Is there a server setting that controls this behavior?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out this indeed is configurable via Group Policy (in my case controlled via Windows domain).
See this link: [http://support.microsoft.com/kb/281262](https://web.archive.org/web/20110718183120/http://support.microsoft.com/kb/281262)

Comment: The link goes to "How To Turn On Remote Desktop Automatic Logon in Windows XP".