# Windows 7 Remote Desktop Connection Save Credentials not working

Tags: windows-7, remote-desktop, windows-server

How to i allow credentials to be saved when connecting to another machine with Remote Desktop Connection?

## Background

i try to connect to a server, and the Remote Desktop Client does not have any saved credentials:

[image]

In order to try to save the credentials i check the option **Allow me to save credentials**:

[image]

i then initiate the connection, enter my password, and notice that the **Remember my credentials** option is checked:

[image]

Once connected to the server, i ensure that the local group policy options

> Local Computer Policy ➞ Computer Configuration ➞ Administrative Templates ➞ Windows Components ➞ Remote Desktop Services ➞ Remote Desktop Connection Client
>
> - Prompt for credentials on the client computer
> - Do not allow passwords to be saved

which default to allowing passwords to be saved, and default to not prompting for credentials, are forced to allow passwords to be saved, and forced to not prompt for passwords:

[image]

And i run `gpupdate /force` to ensure the **forced off** security settings are in use.

Repeat the above steps 4 or 5 times, on the 6th time creating screenshots for [a stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11847805/windows-7-remote-desktop-connection-save-credentials-not-working).

Notice that Remote Desktop Connection client refuses to save my password, noting:

> You will be asked for your credentials when you connect

[image]

So the question is: How do save credentials when connecting to a machine?

## Additional things tried

As was suggested:

- in [the (closed) Stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11847805/windows-7-remote-desktop-connection-save-credentials-not-working/11858314#11858314)
- [the Microsoft forum post](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_7-security/remote-desktop-connection-not-using-saved/13a17d84-b008-4767-95fb-b891e9e6bc66)

i tried enabling the *"Allow delegating saved credentials with NTLM-only server authentication"* for `TERMSRV/*` in `gpedit.msc` on the *client* (e.g. Windows 7) machine:

[image]

People suggest this without realizing that it only applies to NTLM authentication. [NTLM is an outdated, insecure, and should not be used](https://serverfault.com/questions/254813/why-use-kerberos-instead-of-ntlm-in-iis/384721#384721):

> NTLM is an outdated authentication protocol with flaws that potentially compromise the security of applications and the operating system. Although Kerberos has been available for many years many applications are still written to use NTLM only. This needlessly reduces the security of applications.

Either way: it didn't work.

## Bonus information

- tried both modern `ian@avatopia.com` and legacy `avatopia.com\ian` username formats
- tried setting the group policy on the domain controller
- Windows 7 64-bit Professional client
- Windows Server 2008 R2 server
- Windows Server 2008 server
- Windows Server 2012 server
- Windows Server 2003 R2 server
- everything from *Background* on is just filler to make it look like i *"attempted some research effort"*; you can ignore it; including this line which talks about ignoring this line

## Appendix A

The client is Windows 7, connecting to Windows Server 2008 R2, over RDP 7.1, with the server using an auto-generated certificate:

[image]

The client has authenticated the identity of the server:

[image]

It also happens when connecting to Windows Server 2008, and Windows Server 2012 (all from Windows 7 client). All machine are joined to the same domain.

## Appendix B

The resultant set of policy (`rsop.msc`) on the client has *Always prompt for password on connect* set to **Disabled**:

[image]

## Appendix C

Results of connecting to every server i can find. i was wrong when i said it fails on any connection to Server **2003**. The problem is limited to Server **2008**, **2008 R2**, and **2012**:

- Windows Server 2000: Yes*
- Windows Server 2000: Yes*
- Windows Server 2003: Yes
- Windows Server 2003 R2: Yes
- Windows Server 2003 R2: Yes (Domain controller)
- Windows Server 2003 R2: Yes
- Windows Server 2008: No
- Windows Server 2008: No
- Windows Server 2008 R2: No
- Windows Server 2008 R2: No
- Windows Server 2012: No
- Windows Server 2012: No

<sup>*</sup>indicates it will use saved credentials, but must re-enter password at 2000 login screen

## Bonus Reading

- KB281262: [How To Turn On Remote Desktop Automatic Logon in Windows XP](https://web.archive.org/web/20150221095334/http://support.microsoft.com:80/kb/281262)
- SuperUser: [Remote Desktop connection is ignoring saved credentials](https://superuser.com/questions/224830/remote-desktop-connection-is-ignoring-saved-credentials)
- Windows Seven Forums: Windows 7: [Remote Desktop Connection Automatic Log On - Allow or Prevent](https://web.archive.org/web/20170116005408/http://www.sevenforums.com:80/tutorials/141937-remote-desktop-connection-automatic-log-allow-prevent.html?)
- Microsoft.com: [Saving and changing logon credentials in Remote Desktop Connection](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/windows?ui=en-US&rs=en-US&ad=US)
- Microsoft.com: [Saving your logon credentials in Remote Desktop Connection](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/windows?ui=en-US&rs=en-US&ad=US)
- MSDN Remote Desktop Services Blog: [Saved credentials do not work](https://web.archive.org/web/20160129055031/http://blogs.msdn.com:80/b/rds/archive/2007/01/22/vista-remote-desktop-connection-authentication-faq.aspx#_Saved_credentials_do)
- Stackoverflow: [Windows 7 Remote Desktop Connection Save Credentials not working [closed]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11847805/windows-7-remote-desktop-connection-save-credentials-not-working)
- Microsoft Forums: [Remote Desktop Connection not using saved credentials](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_7-security/remote-desktop-connection-not-using-saved/13a17d84-b008-4767-95fb-b891e9e6bc66)

Comment: If you go to `Server Manager -> Roles -> Remote Desktop Services -> RD Session Host Configuration` then double click on the connection (likely called 'RDP-Tcp`) what is set for the Certificate on the general tab? I have had issues in the past where if the client did not respect the certificate it would not save the credentials.

Comment: Also the GP settings you show in [your screenshot](http://i.stack.imgur.com/6RrPu.png) are client side settings. Check the what the setting is set to on the client connecting to the server. (use `rsop.msc` to quickly see what the policy settings are set to on the client)

Comment: Are you using RDP 8 ? Is this all happening on one domain, or more ?

Comment: @ScottChamberlain Added screenshot. The general tab says the certificate is *"Auto generated"*.

Comment: Is the client and server in the same domain?

Comment: @harrymc Windows 7 client connecting to Windows Server 2008, Windows Server 2008 R2, and Windows 2012 server. The added screenshot just added says "RDP 7.1". It's all one domain here (`avatopia.com`). It does **not** fail when connecting to Server 2000, 2003, or 2003 R2 (all client connection attempts from same Windows 7 client machine - again, on the same domain as all the servers)

Comment: @ScottChamberlain Yes. Client, and Servers all joined to the same Windows Server 2003 R2 hosted domain.

Comment: So the problems are with Windows Server 2008 / 2008 R2 / 2012 ?

Comment: @harrymc Yes. Windows 7 connecting to <= Server 2003 R2 works. Windows 7 connecting to >= Server 2008 fails. (See **Appendix C** in the question)

Comment: Try using [Royal TS Version 1.5.1](http://www.oldversion.com/windows/royal-ts/) (last freeware version), with which there is no problem of saved credentials. Interesting to know if you will have any problem using it.

Comment: @harrymc Royal TS *does* connect without prompting for credentials during connect.

Comment: @EelcoLigtvoet i did try saving an RDP file; no effect

Comment: I wonder if there is a reg file or something that you could just click and get it over with, rather then for each new machine scouting for these settings again and again...

Comment: `"Always prompt for password"` set to *`Disabled`* instead of "Enabled" or "Not configured" works for some server 2008 R2 and 2012 target remote machine.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

i found the solution. It was at the same time both subtle, and obvious.

As mentioned in the question, when i was modifying the following **Remote Desktop Connection Client** Group Policy settings:

- Prompt for credentials on the client computer
- Do not allow passwords to be saved

i was checking them on the *server*:

[image]

i thought it would be the **server** that dictates what the **client** is allowed to do. Turns out that is completely wrong. It was [@mpy's answer](https://superuser.com/a/606331/8169) (while incorrect), which led me to the solution. i shouldn't be looking at the RDP client policy on the RDP *server*, i need to look at the RDP client policy on my RDP **client** machine:

[image]

On my client Windows 7 machine, the policy was:

- Do not allow passwords to be saved: Enabled
- Prompt for credentials on the client computer: Enabled

i do not know when these options were enabled (i did not enable them in recent memory). The confusing part is that even though

> **Do not allow passwords to be saved**

is Enabled, the RDP client would still **save** password; but only for servers below Windows Server 2008.

The truth table of functioning:

```
Do not allow saved  Prompt for creds  Works for 2008+ servers  Works for 2003 R2- servers
==================  ================  =======================  ==========================
Enabled             Enabled           No                       Yes
Enabled             Not Configured    No                       No
Not Configured      Enabled           Yes                      Yes
Not Configured      Not Configured    Yes                      Yes
```

So there is the trick. The group policy settings under:

> **Computer Configuration\Policies\Administrative Templates\Windows Components\Terminal Services\Remote Desktop Connection Client**

on the **client** machine need to be configured with:

- Do not allow passwords to be saved: **Not Configured** *(critical)*
- Prompt for credentials on the client computer: **Not Configured**

The other source of confusion is that while

- a domain **Enabled** policy cannot override a local **Disabled**
- a domain **Disabled** policy **can** be overridden by a local **Enabled** policy

Which again leads to a truth table:

```
Domain Policy   Local Policy    Effective Policy
==============  ==============  ==============================
Not Configured  Not Configured  Not configured (i.e. disabled)
Not Configured  Disabled        Disabled
Not Configured  Enabled         Enabled
Disabled        Not Configured  Disabled
Disabled        Disabled        Disabled
Disabled        Enabled         Disabled (client wins)
Enabled         Not Configured  Enabled
Enabled         Disabled        Enabled (domain wins)
Enabled         Enabled         Enabled
```

Comment: In Windows 10 the location is `Computer Configuration\Administrative Templates\Windows Components\Remote Desktop Services\Remote Desktop Connection Client`.

Answer (score 12):

Since the direct answer to the question is already there, I'll suggest an alternative approach.

[Remote Desktop Connection Manager](https://www.microsoft.com/en-ca/download/details.aspx?id=44989) (RDCMan) is a tool written by Julian Burger and [used internally in Microsoft](http://blogs.technet.com/b/exchange/archive/2010/06/11/3410093.aspx). It's very lightweight and free and in my opinion it greatly improves productivity, especially when you maintain many connections. And yes, it stores passwords too (in xml configuration file).

[image: Remote desktop connection manager]

Advantages:

- You can organize connections in hierarchies, which inherit properties (e.g. credentials, color settings, resolution).
- All configuration, including hashed passwords, is stored in one file - easy to move between computers.
- Lightweight, free, reliable.

Disadvantages:

- Some people don't like the navigation menu on the left when not in full screen mode. Personally, I got used to it quickly.
- It seems not to handle non-standard DPI settings well. For example, when I use the 125% zoom in Windows display settings and I find in RDP connections is a bit blurry. For that reason, on some machines I use [Microsoft Remote Desktop](https://apps.microsoft.com/store/detail/microsoft-remote-desktop/9WZDNCRFJ3PS?hl=en-us&gl=US) instead. It handles this situation better.

Screenshot from the article:
[How Sysadmins RDP efficiently using Remote Desktop Connection Manager](http://www.sysadminlab.net/windows/how-sysadmins-rdp-efficiently-using-remote-desktop-connection-manager)

Comment: For lack of reason/real answer (gpolicy is fine on both of mine) this serves. And more specifically: it works. It stopped asking for passwords twice. (once via host (win7 saved password rdp entry) and once via remote (server 2012r2) even though I'm already logged in - just dc'd)

Comment: I don't know how I've never used this before.  I use RDP *DAILY* on numerous servers.  This is a productivity saver!  WOW.  Thank you!

Answer (score 6):

The most detailed answer is already there, made by asker. I only want to note that this problem may also happen when client computer OS is a home SKU, thus no local GP editor may be available, neither a domain policy is in effect. Nevertheless, the client may act as if the policy to always ask password is set (don't know what causes such a default - maybe some program installed?).

Then, it is useful to set the policy registry setting manually (MS RDP client checks it; you may find it using a tool like procmon). It is here:

```
[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Policies\Microsoft\Windows NT\Terminal Services]

"PromptForCredsOnClient"=dword:00000000

"DisablePasswordSaving"=dword:00000000
```

Answer (score 3):

Reading through your questions, I stumbled over this Group Policy setting: `Prompt for credentials on the client computer` which you *disabled*.

[MS Technet](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc753945%28v=WS.10%29.aspx) gives the following explanation on this setting:

> ### **`Prompt for credentials on the client computer`**
>
> This policy setting
>   determines whether a user will be prompted on the client computer to
>   provide credentials for a remote connection to a terminal server.
>
> If you **enable** this policy setting, a user will be prompted on the
>   client computer—instead of on the terminal server—to provide
>   credentials for a remote connection to a terminal server. **If saved
>   credentials for the user are available on the client computer, the
>   user will not be prompted to provide credentials.**
>
> *Note*   If you enable
>   this policy setting and a user is prompted on both the client computer
>   and on the terminal server to provide credentials, run the Terminal
>   Services Configuration tool on the terminal server, and in the
>   Properties dialog box for the connection, clear the Always prompt for
>   password check box on the Log on Settings tab.
>
> If you **disable** or do not configure this policy setting, **the version of
>   the operating system on the terminal server will determine when a user
>   is prompted to provide credentials for a remote connection to a
>   terminal server**. For Windows 2000 and Windows Server 2003, a user will
>   be prompted on the terminal server to provide credentials for a remote
>   connection. For Windows Server 2008, a user will be prompted on the
>   client computer to provide credentials for a remote connection.

That sound exactly to be the scenario you are facing. You want to save the credentials on the client machine, so just *enable* the `Prompt for credentials on the client computer` setting.

Answer (score 3):

In my case, the issue was that the `*.rdp` file downloaded from Microsoft Azure had the following line:

```
prompt for credentials:i:1
```

Normally checking 'save credentials' would change that line, but for some reason it also comes marked as 'read-only'.

---

Unmarking it as 'read-only' and changing the line to

```
prompt for credentials:i:0
```

in notepad fixed the issue.

Comment: This was driving me crazy, I had to keep looking up passwords and probably wasted several hours over the last year. No idea why they do this. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

I've tried all possible options and nothing help.
I have resolved the issue by resetting the password that is stored in Windows Vault for RDP connection.

Steps to do:

1. Right click on RDP connection icon => Edit
2. Select "Always ask for credentials"
3. Connect. Input the right password and select "Remember my credentials"

That's all.

PS: The problem was caused by some Windows update.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest using using [Royal TS](http://www.royalts.com/main/home.aspx) that does credential management much better
than the mess that Microsoft's RDP does of it.

The latest version is commercial, starting at $35 for the individual license.

Or you can opt for [Version 1.5.1](http://www.oldversion.com/windows/royal-ts/), which is the last freeware version, that looks
quite sufficient to do the job.

Comment: Unfortunately RoyalTS doesn't handle full-screen, 32-bit color, is a separate download. And switching to another client doesn't solve the problem in this client.

Comment: The freeware version supports full-screen, but in 24-bit. If that's not enough, perhaps the newer commercial version (trial available) can do better.

Comment: If i did own RoyalTS: my question still stands. Especially for people who are have never been able to solve this problem for the last five years; and came to SuperUser hoping for a solution.

Comment: Don't 'advertise' paid or shareware products.This does not answer the question and these types of 'answers' get quite annoying.

Comment: RDCMan is adequate without getting into paid or crippled/lite/shareware 'free' software. So why add this? Try https://superuser.com/a/606433/47628 - completely free.

Comment: @bshea: Because Version 1.5.1 is very good and simple to use.

Answer (score 0):

Don't know why, but this worked:

(Using Windows 7 Home Basic) 
I did not preconfigure my username in the Remote Desktop Connection options window.  Instead, I connected to the remote host and waited for the credentials (Windows Security) prompt. And then I gave the credentials
(username and password) and checked the option to remember my credentials.

There is no group policy editor for Windows 7 Home Basic. Also, RDCMan (as suggested [in another answer](https://superuser.com/questions/604483/windows-7-remote-desktop-connection-save-credentials-not-working/606433#606433)) did not help.

Comment: My answer to [Windows 7 (Home Premium): eventvwr.exe: How to log workstation locking and unlocking and screensaver invoked and dismissed events](https://superuser.com/a/991644) shows how to install gpedit.msc on Windows Starter Edition, Home and Home Premium

Answer (score 0):

What worked for me was what is suggested in the Stack Overflow question you referred to. (https://stackoverflow.com/q/11847805/4330815)
Not sure why it didn't work for you without that additional changes you mentioned, but according to what you wrote I guess you modified only 1 setting out of the 4 (the "Allow delegating saved credentials with NTLM-only server authentication" one)
Either way thanks a lot for the details you provided.