# Creation of a remote desktop connection file (RDP) with password embedded in it

Tags: remote-desktop, passwords, remote-access

I need to connect to several RDP's and switch between them quite frequently.

Therefore I was wondering how to save all my RDP's along with the password, so that I could just click them to open the connection without manually entering the password every time in other words an application that would ask me for the host name, user and password for the first time I use it and save them for the next log on session.

Comment: Teamviewer's unattended access works like that.

Answer (score 5):

You can save the password in RDP and save them to your desktop, then you can just open them from the destkop shortcut

[image]

Then click Save As and give it a name and save to where you want to save it. Now you can open it by opening the shortcut without having to re-enter the details

If you can't save then see this post [Windows 7 Remote Desktop Connection Save Credentials not working](https://superuser.com/questions/604483/windows-7-remote-desktop-connection-save-credentials-not-working)

Comment: Thank you very much for reply. But the administrator of the connecting computer has not given me enough rights to save my credentials.

Answer (score 1):

If you manage lots of host using remote desktop, and each one may have different username / passwords, you may want to consider something like [mRemoteNG](http://www.mremoteng.org/)

Comment: Thanks a ton for the reply. I will definitely give it a try.

Comment: @spaniard89, you have logged in this year, why have you not responded to those people who have taken the time to answer you? Did this help?