# Windows 7 (Home Premium): eventvwr.exe: How to log workstation locking and unlocking and screensaver invoked and dismissed events

Tags: windows-7, windows, login, event-log, event-viewer

I have found the following information pertaining to when a user starts and stops interacting with a Windows 7 Home Premium 64-bit PC. Theoretically, these events can be viewed in `eventvwr.exe` when run as Administrator.

However, I have tried locking and unlocking the workstation and nothing shows up in the log. What must I do to enable this behavior?

Logon Session Events

- 4624  Successful logon
- 4647  User initiated logoff
- 4625  Logon failure (See Logon Failure Codes)
- 4778  Remote desktop session reconnected
- 4779  Remote desktop session disconnected
- 4800  Workstation locked
- 4801  Workstation unlocked
- 4802  Screen saver invoked
- 4803  Screen saver dismissed

---

UPDATE:

@DavidPostill, I have tried the solution below, downloading and running the file you mentioned, and copying the `C:\SysWOW64\gpedit.msc` file to `C:\Windows\System32\gpedit.exe`, but I ran into the following problem:

The files `C:\SysWOW64\GroupPolicy` and `C:\SysWOW64\GroupPolicyUsers` could not be copied to `C:\Windows\System32\GroupPolicy` and `C:\Windows\System32\GroupPolicyUsers` because these folders already existed.

Here is what I get when I run `gpedit.msc`:

[image]

Comment: Were you logged in as an Adminstrator when you tried to copy the directories? Can you try just copy the **contents** of `C:\SysWOW64\GroupPolicy` and paste to `C:\Windows\System32\GroupPolicy`? Note `C:\SysWOW64\GroupPolicyUser` is an empty directory so that shouldn't be a problem.

Comment: The only other thing I can think of is that you have a non English version of Windows ... (Italian?)

Comment: Yes, but the filenames should be the same even in my localized Italian version of Windows... ?

Answer (score 0):

#### What must I do to enable logging of Logon Session Events?

Use the Group Policy Editor (`gpedit.msc`) to enable auditing of Account Logon Events in the Windows Security Event Log.

Note: Windows Starter Edition, Home and Home Premium do not include `gpedit.msc`. Instructions to install it are provided later in this answer.

To enable auditing of Account Logon Events:

1. Run gpedit.msc
2. Select "Windows Settings" > "Security Settings" > "Local Policies" > "Audit Policy"

   [image: ![enter image description here]
3. Right click "Audit account logon events" and select "Properties"
4. Check "Success" and "Failure" as appropriate, then click "OK"

   [image: ![enter image description here]

---

#### How do I install gpedit.msc on Windows Starter Edition, Home and Home Premium?

I used the following procedure to successfully install `gpedit.msc` on Windows 7 64 bit Home Premium.

It apparently works on Windows 8 and Windows 8.1 as well.

> UPDATE: According to some readers, this tool also works fine in Windows 8 and Windows 8.1.
>
> Today we are going to share a simple installer which installs the required system files in Windows so that you can enjoy Group Policy Editor in all Windows 7 editions.
>
> 1. First download the setup file using following link:
>
>    [Download Group Policy Editor Installer](http://jwils876.deviantart.com/art/Add-GPEDIT-msc-215792914)
>
>    You'll find the download link in right-side section of the above
>      mentioned page.
> 2. After downloading the ZIP file, extract it using WinRAR or 7-Zip.
> 3. Run the extracted setup.exe file.
>
>    It will install the files and you'll be able to access gpedit.msc
>      command via RUN or Start Menu search box.
>
> Note:
>
> - For Windows 7 64-bit (x64) users! You'll also need to go to "SysWOW64" folder present in "C:\Windows" folder and copy
>     "GroupPolicy", "GroupPolicyUsers" folders and gpedit.msc file from
>     there and paste them in "C:\Windows\System32" folder.
>
> If you are getting "MMC could not create the snap-in" error message
>   while running gpedit.msc, check out following steps to fix the
>   problem. Basically it happens when your username in Windows contains
>   more than one word.
>
> 1. Run the installer and leave it at the last step (do not click on the "Finish" button).
> 2. Now go to `C:\Windows\Temp\gpedit\` folder.
> 3. If you are running 32-bit (x86) edition of Windows 7, right-click on x86.bat file and choose "Open With -> Notepad" option. If you are
>      running 64-bit (x64) edition of Windows 7, right-click on x64.bat file
>      and choose "Open With -> Notepad" option.
> 4. You'll find a total of 6 lines containing the following string in the file:
>
>    %username%:f
> 5. Edit those lines and replace `%username%:f` with `"%username%":f`
>
>    Original: `icacls %WinDir%\SysWOW64\gpedit.dll /grant:r %username%:f`
>
>    New: `icacls %WinDir%\SysWOW64\gpedit.dll /grant:r "%username%":f`
> 6. Save and run the file (right-click -> Run as Administrator).
> 7. That's it. You'll have working gpedit.msc.

Source [How to Enable "Group Policy Editor" (gpedit.msc) in Windows 7 Home Premium, Home Basic and Starter Editions?](http://www.askvg.com/how-to-enable-group-policy-editor-gpedit-msc-in-windows-7-home-premium-home-basic-and-starter-editions/)

Comment: thank you so much for your answer. Wish it would work for me...