# Windows 7 Home Premium: Event ID 4624: Someone logged in when I was away

Tags: windows-7, event-log, event-viewer

I know for certain that I was away from my Windows 7 Home Premium laptop between 12:35 and 14:37. But the `eventvwr.exe` shows the following:

- 28/10/2015 14:54:25 Event ID 4624 (access type: 2)
- 28/10/2015 14:36:44 Event ID 4624 (access type: 7)
- 28/10/2015 13:08:52 Event ID 4624 (access type: 5)
- 28/10/2015 12:19:01 Event ID 4624 (access type: 5)
- 28/10/2015 12:17:59 Event ID 4624 (access type: 2)

It seems like someone (who has the key to my living place) logged in at 13:08:52 when I was away.

How is this possible?

I am absolutely certain that nobody knows my password.
It is unique and I don't use it anywhere else.

Is there a way Event ID 4624 could correspond to something other than a physical person logging in, or is there some way someone could enter by brute force that I am not aware of? Thanks.

---

EDIT: Here are the details pertaining to the access at 13:08:52 (once again, sorry if the log is in Italian, I am running a localized version of Windows):

```
Accesso di un account riuscito.

Soggetto:
    ID sicurezza:       SYSTEM
    Nome account:       NEIL-PC$
    Dominio account:        WORKGROUP
    ID accesso:     0x3e7

Tipo di accesso:            5

Nuovo accesso:
    ID sicurezza:       SYSTEM
    Nome account:       SYSTEM
    Dominio account:        NT AUTHORITY
    ID accesso:     0x3e7
    GUID accesso:       {00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000}

Informazioni sul processo:
    ID processo:        0x2a0
    Nome processo:      C:\Windows\System32\services.exe

Informazioni di rete:
    Nome workstation:   
    Indirizzo rete di origine:  -
    Porta di origine:       -

Informazioni di autenticazione dettagliate:
    Processo di accesso:        Advapi  
    Pacchetto di autenticazione:    Negotiate
    Servizi transitati: -
    Nome pacchetto (solo NTLM): -
    Lunghezza chiave:       0

Questo evento viene generato quando viene creata una sessione di accesso. Viene generato nel computer in cui è stato effettuato l'accesso.

Il campo Soggetto indica l'account nel sistema locale che ha richiesto l'accesso. Generalmente si tratta di un servizio, quale il servizio Server, o di un processo locale, ad esempio Winlogon.exe o Services.exe.

Il campo Tipo di accesso indica il tipo di accesso che è stato effettuato. I tipi più comuni sono 2 (interattivo) e 3 (rete).

Il campo Nuovo accesso indica l'account per il quale è stato creato il nuovo accesso, vale a dire l'account che ha effettuato l'accesso.

Il campo Informazioni di rete indica l'origine della richiesta di accesso remota. Il nome della workstation non è sempre disponibile e può essere vuoto in alcuni casi.

Il campo Informazioni di autenticazione fornisce informazioni dettagliate sulla specifica richiesta di accesso.
    - GUID accesso è un identificatore univoco che può essere utilizzato per correlare questo evento a un evento KDC.
    - Servizi transitati indica quali servizi intermedi hanno partecipato alla richiesta di accesso.
    - Nome pacchetto indica quale sottoprotocollo dei protocolli NTLM è stato utilizzato.
    - Lunghezza chiave indica la lunghezza della chiave di sessione generata. Se non è stata richiesta alcuna chiave di sessione, la lunghezza sarà pari a zero.
```

Comment: Why not look at the detail of the event and see what account was logging in?  Could have been a system account.

Comment: I've updated my post. Could you make out the kind of access?

Comment: @Paul, could you please help me... the access type is set to 5, and the message says the most common access types are 2 for interactive, and 3 for a network access. Any ideas what 5 stands for?

Comment: Logon Type 5 - Service, from http://www.windowsecurity.com/articles-tutorials/misc_network_security/Logon-Types.html. So just system services doing their thing.

Answer (score 5):

> SYSTEM Nome account: SYSTEM

I dont speak italian but this looks like a system action...

Comment: Thanks. The problem I am having is that my version of windows doesn't log unlock and lock events, which leaves a shade of doubt. Could you please help me find some other things to look for as evidence on this version of Windows 7 of an intrusion? It's very important to me.

Comment: @JordanJamingsons Your copy of Windows DOES log Unlocks, that's what Logon/Access Type 7 is (i.e.: `28/10/2015 14:36:44 Event ID 4624 (access type: 7)`).

Comment: Thanks, now that's a great comment. Now what I need is to find a screen lock event. If the screen did not lock within the amount of time set in the control panel I will know someone accessed my computer. I would really really really appreciate help with this...

Comment: @Ƭᴇcʜιᴇ007, I don't get it. You say that access type 7 is a screen unlock, whereas the [answer to this post](http://superuser.com/questions/991597/windows-7-home-premium-eventvwr-exe-how-to-log-workstation-locking-and-unloc) says event locks and unlocks cannot be logged in Home Premium. What is the truth?

Comment: There's a difference between logging the Locks and Unlocks, and Logging in successfully after unlocking.  The latter is what you have, the former is what you need Pro for.

Answer (score 2):

> Nome processo:      C:\Windows\System32\services.exe

This says the process name that requested the logon was [Services.exe](http://www.neuber.com/taskmanager/process/services.exe.html), which is the file used by Windows to control system services.

> Nome account:       SYSTEM

The name of the account that ran `Services.exe` is `SYSTEM`, which is the [system account](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/120929) (Windows itself).

> Tipo di accesso:            5

Type of Access/Logon Type: 5 means "Service".

[Here's a complete list of logon types](https://www.ultimatewindowssecurity.com/securitylog/encyclopedia/event.aspx?eventID=4624)

So it was Windows starting a service, and that service is set to login as the System account.

This is all perfectly normal.