# How to permanently disable a built-in keyboard

Tags: keyboard, uninstall

I spilled some liquids on my laptop, after which I dismantled it and cleaned it. Everything worked fine, except my keyboard.

I installed an USB keyboard.

When the laptop is getting hot and the laptop fan is getting noisy, some keys of the original built-in keyboard are still working (tab-key and ctrl-key). As a temporary solution I uninstalled the built-in keyboard driver (device manager windows 10 - uninstall 'Standard PS/2 keyboard' - but I didn't rebooted because the driver would be automatically reinstalled).

But the keyboard is still reacting sometimes (tab-key and ctrl-key).

There is already another topic about this: [How can I disable my laptop's built-in keyboard in Windows 7?](https://superuser.com/questions/346570/how-can-i-disable-my-laptops-built-in-keyboard-in-windows-7) but

- I couldn't find the 'gpedit.msc'
- I don't have an Acer
- disabling the built-in keyboard hasn't worked, the keyboard still reacts when the laptop is getting hot

I have a HP Pavilion g7 using windows 10.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I disable my laptop's built-in keyboard in Windows 7?](http://superuser.com/questions/346570/how-can-i-disable-my-laptops-built-in-keyboard-in-windows-7)

Comment: There's more than one solution to that question you've linked.  Since you're on a Home version if Windows, explore the other answers.  I'd advise following [the one that suggests you open the notebook and detach the keyboard](http://superuser.com/a/346586/23133).

Comment: Can a laptop boot if he doesn't find a keyboard? Or does my USB keyboard been connected at any time?

Comment: BTW: you can get a new [replacement keyboard for that notebook for like less than $30](http://www.amazon.ca/g7-2002xx-g7-2010nr-g7-2017cl-g7-2017us-g7-2022us/dp/B00H1SNBE6)

Comment: It should be able to boot. Here's a crazy idea -- why not try it? ;)

Comment: Windows Starter Edition, Home and Home Premium do not include gpedit.msc. Instructions to install it are in this answer [Windows 7 (Home Premium): eventvwr.exe: How to log workstation locking and unlocking and screensaver invoked and dismissed events](http://superuser.com/a/991644)

Answer (score 0):

Since you are up for dismantling (and have already been there once), just unplug it internally.

Answer (score 0):

I would recromend if software doesnt work, just unplug it, if you can safely take it apart, i would just find the cable (usually a wide ish ribbon cable) and unplug it.

Answer (score 0):

Use the group policy called “**Prevent installation of devices that match any of this device IDs**”. We can enable this group policy and add the device ID of our laptop keyboard to fix the problem. For that, first we have to find the device ID of our laptop keyboard.

You have to find your device ID using device manager and add that ID to above group policy.

Find that group policy under

> Computer Configuration → Administrative Templates → System → Device
> Installation → Device Installation Restrictions

Uninstall the laptop keyboard drivers after enabling the group policy. You can find detailed guide with images in [this link](http://Computer%20Configuration%20%E2%86%92%20Administrative%20Templates%20%E2%86%92%20System%20%E2%86%92%20Device%20Installation%20%E2%86%92%20Device%20Installation%20Restrictions) if you need further information.