# Remote Desktop Client suddenly stopped remembering passwords

Tags: windows, windows-10, remote-desktop, credentials

All was good an nice on my Windows 10 desktop: the Remote Desktop Connection was remembering more than 10 different credentials to Win 2012 servers, Win 10 desktops etc. However, suddenly it does not remember anymore to any, even I explicitly checking again and again the "Remember Me" checkbox.

This machine is not in a domain, it's a home computer. So it was either the Windows 10 update, or some other magic which changed the things...

**What I've tried so far**

I've read and tried everything in this Q/A [Windows 7 Remote Desktop Connection Save Credentials not working](https://superuser.com/questions/604483/windows-7-remote-desktop-connection-save-credentials-not-working)

Answer (score 0):

Well this is embarrassing, but the same time also a very disturbing UX also...

I saw this **immediately** after launching RDP and checked the checkbox repeatedly:

[image]

But in the background...

[image]

Cancelling the dialog on top, then unchecking the "Always..." solved the "problem".